# Android debugger does not attach with send intent?

Tags: android, adb

in my application when i put break point to any other activity debugger works, and debugger attach and shows on my device screen every time when i run it in debugging mode.

Now strange problem is when i use send intent debugger does not appear in that code or does not stop on break point :(

**I have done enough research:**
1) By attaching bug icon to the process.
2) My device is set to debug usb in settings.
3) Tried to restart ADB already
4) Tried to restart Eclipse,Machine already

nothing worked.

**My Menifest file**

```
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".MyShareMenu">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
               <data android:mimeType="*/*" ></data>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
```

kindly guide me what could be the issue?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried at-least everything to make debugger work, as i have already mentioned in above steps.

Finally i fixed this issue by just restarting the phone :)
Its wired but it resolved my problem.